# Python finance - Load in specific values for predetermined dates

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm fairly new to python and pandas, so this might be obvious for some of you. I need to get data from a .csv file at predetermined dates that I have stored in an excel sheet. The data in question are the Fama and French 3- and 5-factor model data, which is available for download on the author's webpage. My current idea is something like this:

```
""" load dates from excel sheet """
for d in dates:
    start_date = dates[d]
    end_date = start_date.dateoffset(60 months)
```

And then I need the loop to use the start and end date to find the data in the .csv file containing the factor model(s). Can anybody help me here? Hope this question makes sense, thanks!

Comment: how big is the file? if it can fit in memory, it'll be a lot easier to read the whole thing and then select the dates you want from that. no loops needed.

Comment: I have a sample of ~ 1.600 financial events, each having unique dates. Its for these dates that I need to find the corresponding dates and returns in the file with the Fama and French factors.

Comment: ok. same theory applies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load entire file to pandas dataframe then you can try something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])  
time_range= (df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)
df = df.loc[time_range]
```

Comment: I still have to use two dataframes, but this looks like it will do the trick. Thanks!